# string input to dplyr group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, nse

I need to understand how to input string values (NSE) in dplyr's group_by function. My data set and code below works fine with "group_by" but does not work with "group_by_" version. I am unable to find my mistake in this regard.

```
ID,Region,Dimension,BlogsInd.,BlogsNews,BlogsTech,Columns
1,PK,Dim1,-4.75,NA,NA,NA
2,PK,Dim1,-5.69,NA,NA,NA
3,PK,Dim1,-0.27,NA,NA,NA
4,PK,Dim1,-2.76,NA,NA,NA
5,PK,Dim1,-8.24,NA,NA,NA
6,PK,Dim1,-12.51,NA,NA,NA
7,PK,Dim1,-1.28,NA,NA,NA
8,PK,Dim1,0.95,NA,NA,NA
9,PK,Dim1,-5.96,NA,NA,NA
10,PK,Dim1,-8.81,NA,NA,NA
11,PK,Dim1,-8.46,NA,NA,NA
12,PK,Dim1,-6.15,NA,NA,NA
13,PK,Dim1,-13.98,NA,NA,NA
14,PK,Dim1,-16.43,NA,NA,NA
15,PK,Dim1,-4.09,NA,NA,NA
16,PK,Dim1,-11.06,NA,NA,NA
17,PK,Dim1,-9.04,NA,NA,NA
18,PK,Dim1,-8.56,NA,NA,NA
19,PK,Dim1,-8.13,NA,NA,NA
20,PK,Dim2,-14.46,NA,NA,NA
21,PK,Dim2,-4.21,NA,NA,NA
22,PK,Dim2,-4.96,NA,NA,NA
23,PK,Dim2,-5.48,NA,NA,NA
24,PK,Dim2,-4.53,NA,NA,NA
25,PK,Dim2,6.31,NA,NA,NA
26,PK,Dim2,-11.16,NA,NA,NA
27,PK,Dim2,-1.27,NA,NA,NA
28,PK,Dim2,-11.49,NA,NA,NA
29,PK,Dim2,-0.9,NA,NA,NA
30,PK,Dim2,-12.27,NA,NA,NA
31,PK,Dim2,6.85,NA,NA,NA
32,PK,Dim2,-5.21,NA,NA,NA
33,PK,Dim2,-1.06,NA,NA,NA
34,PK,Dim2,-2.6,NA,NA,NA
35,PK,Dim2,-0.95,NA,NA,NA
36,PK,Dim3,-0.82,NA,NA,NA
37,PK,Dim3,-7.65,NA,NA,NA
38,PK,Dim3,0.64,NA,NA,NA
39,PK,Dim3,-2.25,NA,NA,NA
40,PK,Dim3,-1.58,NA,NA,NA
41,PK,Dim3,-5.73,NA,NA,NA
42,PK,Dim3,0.37,NA,NA,NA
43,PK,Dim3,-5.46,NA,NA,NA
44,PK,Dim3,-3.48,NA,NA,NA
45,PK,Dim3,0.88,NA,NA,NA
46,PK,Dim3,-2.11,NA,NA,NA
47,PK,Dim3,-10.13,NA,NA,NA
48,PK,Dim3,-2.08,NA,NA,NA
49,PK,Dim3,-4.33,NA,NA,NA
50,PK,Dim3,1.09,NA,NA,NA
51,PK,Dim3,-4.23,NA,NA,NA
52,PK,Dim3,-1.46,NA,NA,NA
53,PK,Dim3,9.37,NA,NA,NA
54,PK,Dim3,5.84,NA,NA,NA
55,PK,Dim3,8.21,NA,NA,NA
56,PK,Dim3,7.34,NA,NA,NA
57,PK,Dim4,1.83,NA,NA,NA
58,PK,Dim4,14.39,NA,NA,NA
59,PK,Dim4,22.02,NA,NA,NA
60,PK,Dim4,4.83,NA,NA,NA
61,PK,Dim4,-3.24,NA,NA,NA
62,PK,Dim4,-5.69,NA,NA,NA
63,PK,Dim4,-22.92,NA,NA,NA
64,PK,Dim4,0.41,NA,NA,NA
65,PK,Dim4,-4.42,NA,NA,NA
66,PK,Dim4,-10.72,NA,NA,NA
67,PK,Dim4,-11.29,NA,NA,NA
68,PK,Dim4,-2.89,NA,NA,NA
69,PK,Dim4,-7.59,NA,NA,NA
70,PK,Dim4,-7.45,NA,NA,NA
71,US,Dim1,-12.49,NA,NA,NA
72,US,Dim1,-11.59,NA,NA,NA
73,US,Dim1,-4.6,NA,NA,NA
74,US,Dim1,-22.83,NA,NA,NA
75,US,Dim1,-4.83,NA,NA,NA
76,US,Dim1,-14.76,NA,NA,NA
77,US,Dim1,-15.93,NA,NA,NA
78,US,Dim1,-2.78,NA,NA,NA
79,US,Dim1,-16.39,NA,NA,NA
80,US,Dim1,-15.22,NA,NA,NA
81,US,Dim1,3.25,NA,NA,NA
82,US,Dim1,-2.73,NA,NA,NA
83,US,Dim1,0.96,NA,NA,NA
84,US,Dim1,-1.12,NA,NA,NA
85,US,Dim1,-0.33,NA,NA,NA
86,US,Dim1,-6.45,NA,NA,NA
87,US,Dim1,2.52,NA,NA,NA
88,US,Dim1,3.18,NA,NA,NA
89,US,Dim1,4.65,NA,NA,NA
90,US,Dim2,-1.75,NA,NA,NA
91,US,Dim2,-0.22,NA,NA,NA
92,US,Dim2,8.16,NA,NA,NA
93,US,Dim2,1.89,NA,NA,NA
94,US,Dim2,4.31,NA,NA,NA
95,US,Dim2,-0.41,NA,NA,NA
96,US,Dim2,-23.02,NA,NA,NA
97,US,Dim2,3.87,NA,NA,NA
98,US,Dim2,-4.76,NA,NA,NA
99,US,Dim2,4.95,NA,NA,NA
100,US,Dim2,4.78,NA,NA,NA
101,US,Dim2,-15.11,NA,NA,NA
102,US,Dim2,-3.74,NA,NA,NA
103,US,Dim2,-6.15,NA,NA,NA
104,US,Dim2,-8.33,NA,NA,NA
105,US,Dim2,-5.55,NA,NA,NA
106,US,Dim3,-5.1,NA,NA,NA
107,US,Dim3,-0.41,NA,NA,NA
108,US,Dim3,-8,NA,NA,NA
109,US,Dim3,-11.8,NA,NA,NA
110,US,Dim3,-10.39,NA,NA,NA
111,US,Dim3,-14.98,NA,NA,NA
112,US,Dim3,-13.14,NA,NA,NA
113,US,Dim3,-16.06,NA,NA,NA
114,US,Dim3,-16.75,NA,NA,NA
115,US,Dim3,-17.58,NA,NA,NA
116,US,Dim3,-13.12,NA,NA,NA
117,US,Dim3,-15.69,NA,NA,NA
118,US,Dim3,-9.29,NA,NA,NA
119,US,Dim3,-14.93,NA,NA,NA
120,US,Dim3,-18.75,NA,NA,NA
121,US,Dim3,-16.15,NA,NA,NA
122,US,Dim3,-14.38,NA,NA,NA
123,US,Dim3,-11.33,NA,NA,NA
124,US,Dim3,2.06,NA,NA,NA
125,US,Dim3,1.55,NA,NA,NA
126,US,Dim3,3.17,NA,NA,NA
127,US,Dim4,3.33,NA,NA,NA
128,US,Dim4,-3.31,NA,NA,NA
129,US,Dim4,5.67,NA,NA,NA
130,US,Dim4,-1.94,NA,NA,NA
131,US,Dim4,-4.2,NA,NA,NA
132,US,Dim4,-13.53,NA,NA,NA
133,US,Dim4,-10.84,NA,NA,NA
134,US,Dim4,-1.04,NA,NA,NA
135,US,Dim4,-8.02,NA,NA,NA
136,US,Dim4,-14.65,NA,NA,NA
137,US,Dim4,-6.39,NA,NA,NA
138,US,Dim4,-3.69,NA,NA,NA
139,US,Dim4,-11.62,NA,NA,NA
140,US,Dim4,-3.02,NA,NA,NA
141,US,Dim4,-28.84,NA,NA,NA
```

.

```
attach(dims_Blog)
d1 <- dims_Blog %>% group_by(Dimension, Region) %>% summarise(mean=mean(BlogsInd., na.rm=TRUE))
d1
Dimension Region       mean
     <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl>
1      Dim1     PK -3.7385551
2      Dim1     US -4.2264179
3      Dim2     PK  1.9985551
4      Dim2     US  1.3509577
5      Dim3     PK  0.8965019
6      Dim3     US  1.5335199
7      Dim4     PK  1.4830672
8      Dim4     US  0.3913806
```

But the same code with the other version does not work. Where am I wrong?

```
d1 <- dims_Blog %>% group_by_("Dimension", "Region") %>% summarise_(mean="mean(BlogsInd.)", na.rm=TRUE)
> d1
Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
Groups: Dimension [?]

  Dimension Region  mean na.rm
     <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <lgl>
1      Dim1     PK    NA  TRUE
2      Dim1     US    NA  TRUE
3      Dim2     PK    NA  TRUE
4      Dim2     US    NA  TRUE
5      Dim3     PK    NA  TRUE
6      Dim3     US    NA  TRUE
7      Dim4     PK    NA  TRUE
8      Dim4     US    NA  TRUE
```

Comment: What it means is that you can pass the names stored in certain objects instead of the quoted version

Comment: Yes I understand that. I use it in a function (hence i pass string names of relevant objects to group_by_). But as you can see above, it is not working for me. I need to know where is the mistake in the application of "group_by_".

Comment: you may need to use `group_by_(.dots = `

Comment: Result remains the same.

Comment: Don't use `attach`. Ever.

Comment: The `group_by` works fine for me, though you probably want `summarise_(mean = ~mean(BlogsInd., na.rm=TRUE))` or `summarise_(mean = "mean(BlogsInd., na.rm=TRUE)")`.

Comment: Isn't the only problem that your `na.rm` argument is outside of the `mean` call in your second example so it's now created as a separate variable and your mean returns `NA` because there are `NA`'s in your ungrouped data that are now no longer removed? the grouping seems to work fine, since d1 has the same amount of rows in both cases.

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` outside of the quotes does seems to be the problem. I just didn't know how to put it inside because here it is send as argument to mean i.e. inside brackets. I tried to put it outside like this: `"mean(BlogsInd.), na.rm=TRUE"`

Comment: It should be sent to mean, you send it to mean in the first example.

Comment: I already showed the correct code in my comment above?

Comment: And it does not work when string is inside a string object like this `x = "Dimension"
> y = "BlogsInd."
> colour = "Region" > d1 <- dims_Blog %>% group_by_(.dots=x, colour) %>% summarise_(mean = "mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)")`
Error: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : object 'y' not found

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the nse, but in the `na.rm` argument. In the first example you send this argument to mean, in the second example it's split off and `summarise` interprets it as a new variable to be added. By moving the `na.rm` back into the `mean` call I get the same results from both methods:

```
d1 <- dims_Blog %>% group_by(Dimension, Region) %>% summarise(mean=mean(BlogsInd., na.rm=TRUE))
d2 <- dims_Blog %>% group_by_("Dimension", "Region") %>% summarise_(mean="mean(BlogsInd., na.rm=TRUE)")
identical(d1,d2) #Returns TRUE
```

Comment: the problem is that i send the column names as string objects to the function where this function lies. Please see my last comment above which explains that string passed as `y="BlogsInd."` and then `summarise_(mean="mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)")` gives error of object (y) not found.

Comment: That's a different problem, you need to create the string with the variable name in, so `summarise_(mean=paste("mean(",y,", na.rm=TRUE)"))` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the solution i was looking for days. R doesn't make it easy.